# Symfony - Workflow component - Unrecognized option "metadata"

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, workflow

I'm currently working with symfony/flex and the symfony/workflow component v4.2, but i'm having difficulties implementing what was implemented [with symfony 4.1](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-workflow-improvements), more specifically the metadata option in the workflow's configuration.

My workflow.yaml :

```
framework:
    workflows:
        secondment:
            type: workflow
            audit_trail:
                enabled: true
            marking_store:
                type: 'single_state'
                arguments:
                    - state
            supports:
                - AppBundle\Entity\Contract
            initial_place: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_PROPOSAL
            places:
                - !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_PROPOSAL
                - !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_VALIDATED
                - !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_REFUSED
                - !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_CANCELLED
                - !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_COUNTER_OFFER
            transitions:
                make_counter_offer:
                    from: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_PROPOSAL
                    to:   !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_COUNTER_OFFER
                validate_counter_offer:
                    from: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_COUNTER_OFFER
                    to:   !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_VALIDATED
                validate:
                    from: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_PROPOSAL
                    to:   !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_VALIDATED
                refuse:
                    from: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_PROPOSAL
                    to:   !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_REFUSED
                cancel:
                    from: !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_VALIDATED
                    to:   !php/const:AppBundle\Entity\Contract::STATE_CANCELLED
                    metadata:
                        requirements: 'cancellation_reason'
```

Here is a part of my composer.json :

```
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/skeleton": "^3.4",
        "symfony/workflow": "^4.2",
```

I'm getting this error :

```
InvalidConfigurationException:
Unrecognized option "metadata" under "framework.workflows.workflows.secondment.transitions.cancel"
```

So my question is: Are the improvements made in the workflow component 4.1 only available on symfony 4.1 and higher ? Or, as it is specified that the version 4.2 of the component is 3.4 compatible, it should work as well ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I can't find the `metadata` configuration in the documentation, where did you find it?

Comment: @Kirienzo, can you see that configuration key if you run `bin/console config:dump-reference framework` ?

Comment: @goto it's here : https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-workflow-improvements

Comment: @WilliamJanoti I can only see `metadata_update_threshold: '0'`

Answer (score 0):

You have also to use metadata under `secondment:` config:

```
framework:
    workflows:
        secondment:
            type: workflow
            audit_trail:
                enabled: true
            marking_store:
                type: 'single_state'
                arguments:
                    - state
            supports:
                - AppBundle\Entity\Contract

            metadata:
                - requirements: 'cancellation_reason'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't seem to be it, i'm getting the same error.